# How to group all emails from one user into one collection in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

So I really love how Gmail groups for me important conversations. But I have tons of job related emails sent to me automatically from `@googlecode.com` on each project update (`svn commit`) so it looks like  this:

[image]

I rarely read them but I keep them in case I need them some time.

Is it possible to group them all into one email thread/conversation?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do a [search](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6593) for one of the following:

```
@googlecode.com
```

```
from:(*@googlcode.com)
```

Or you can create a [**filter**](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579#0) to automatically [label](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=118708#0) incoming messages from `@googlecode.com`. You can also apply the filter retroactively by selecting `Also apply filter to X matching conversations`.

I suggest using a **filter and label**, as you can choose different ways to handle matching messages. For example, if you want to reduce clutter, you can have messages `Skip the inbox`.